# Autodesk Forge API: How can I access the count of elements of a BIM model that is displayed in the Model browser via the API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to filter out all parents and childs to obtain only BIM model information about the individual elements of the BIM model. In the Model browser the total counts of individual elements are displayed, but I cannot figure out how to get this information via the API. Below is a picture of what I'm am talking about

[image: 1]

How can I access the count of elements of a BIM model that is displayed in the Model browser via the API?

---

**Edit**: The question is a bit more elaborate.

[image: 2]

What we are able to discern is the root and the leaf node (the end node). When we're using this method at the screenshot shown above, we are not able to retrieve the correct parent (which shows the count of the children). Here, I'd like to get the parent named 'NLRS_31_DO_UN_deurblad_hout_opdek_glas_gen_cie:Standaard', when we're navigating from leaf 'CIE_NLRS_31_DO_o1_glas_helder'.

How can I retrieve in this example the lowest child node (in AutoDesk's viewer model browser) indicated with the number '3' from the corresponding leaf node?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the dbId of the parent node `16.12-f...ihw, recht:500x 600` is 1234.

To get its child count, just call [InstanceTree#getChildCount](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Private/InstanceTree/#getchildcount-dbid) on it.

```js
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let it = model.getInstanceTree();
let nChild = it.getChildCount( 1234 ); //!<<< here you go
```

Comment: Hi Eason, I have edited the question, could you please answer the follow up question?